# Why is $0\to\ker\varepsilon\to P_0\xrightarrow\varepsilon N\to 0$ a projective resolution?

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules, exact-sequence, projective-module

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with $1$.

My professor defined $\operatorname{Tor}_i^R(M,N)$ as follows: Tensor a projective resolution $\dots\to P_1\to P_0\to M\to 0$ with $N$ and set
$$\operatorname{Tor}_i^R(M,N):=\ker(P_i\otimes N \to P_{i-1}\otimes N)/\operatorname{im}(P_{i+1}\otimes N\to P_i\otimes N) \text,$$
where $P_{-1}:=0$.

To prove that $\operatorname{Tor}_0^R(M,N)=M\otimes_R N$, I have seen the following argument:

> Choose a projective resolution
>   $$\dots\to P_1\to P_0\xrightarrow\varepsilon M\to 0 \text;$$
>   this gives a short exact sequence
>   $$0\to\ker\varepsilon\to P_0\xrightarrow\varepsilon M\to 0 \text.$$
>   Tensoring with $N$ yields the exact sequence
>   $$0\to\ker\varepsilon\otimes N\to P_0\otimes N\xrightarrow{\varepsilon\otimes\operatorname{id}} M\otimes N\to 0 \text,$$
>   hence
>   $$\operatorname{Tor}_0^R(M,N)=(P_0\otimes_R N)/(\ker\varepsilon\otimes N) \cong M\otimes N \text.$$

Now most of this is clear to me, except: In the sequence
$$0\to \ker\varepsilon\to P_0\xrightarrow\varepsilon M\to0 \text,$$
**why is $\ker\varepsilon$ projective**? Is this even true, or is the definition incomplete and it does not need to be?

Comment: Did you want $P_{-1}=0$ instead of $P_{-1}=M$?

Comment: What are the hypotheses on $R$?

Comment: @Bernard $R$ is an arbitrary commutative unital ring.

Comment: In that case, $\ker\varepsilon$ has no reason to be projective, unless $N$ itself has projective dimension $\le 1$.

Comment: @Bernard I suspected that. But then, how does the alleged proof given in the question work out? I don't see how it is supposed to match the definition...

Comment: Check if there is no hypothesis hidden in the surroundings

Comment: I suspect it's supposed to be free resolution instead of just projective in the start of the proof

Answer (score 1):

In general $\ker \varepsilon$ is not projective, otherwise every module would have a projective resolution of length one. 
Consider the following counter example: Let $R=K[x,y]$ where $K$ is a field and let $M=R/(x,y)$. Let $\epsilon: R \to M$ be the map that sends an element to its residue class. The kernel is the ideal $(x,y)$ which is not projective.

Also tensoring an exact sequence with $N$ does not give an exact sequence in general.